# Biggest windbg pet peeve

Tags: debugging, windbg

What is your biggest pet peeve related to the windbg debugger from microsoft?

(note: I actually really like windbg if I ignore the unpolished UI.)

Answer (score 6):

Attempting to dock a window is almost always the wrong kind of dock the first time until :I move the mouse just right. Why can't it have the docking cues that VS2008 has?

Comment: windbgx (the windows store version) might have improved on this. I don't remember being frustrated by docking behavior after switching to windbgx.

Answer (score 0):

The ridiculous behavior when you attempt to use click-drag to select text on a line that is wider than its physical window.

The pieces of the history window that I need to copy/paste into bug reports are frequently wider than the physical window.  I've gotten so used to the triple-click workaround that I find myself attempting to misuse triple click in other (well behaved) applications.

Answer (score 0):

Key presses are ignored while the focus is in a source window.  It's not like you can edit the source code from inside windbg.  At least there's the Alt-1 workaround.

Answer (score 0):

How insanely slow .kdfiles copies new binaries across the 1394 connection.  It can take up to one minute for a large dll.

Answer (score 0):

Not being able to switch from output window to command window using a key press, I read that 'Alt+1' should work but it doesn't always so I always have to resort to using the mouse. Also sometimes it doesn't remember when I tell it not to ask me everytime if I want to save the workspace when I quit.

Comment: You can press Tab to switch focus between the command prompt and its associated output window. Tab again to go back. If the cursor is already in the output window, typing any character will first switch to the command prompt and then insert the character.